# Flask post request on page load error

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Whenever i refresh my page, a post request occurs, seen in my console. This means it requests my form before i have entered anything or clicked any buttons. I need to pass this to Jinja and through js, however, it will always return 0 as there is no data in the variables username or password.

```
@app.route('/dosomething', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def dosomething():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        check = system.add_user(username,password)
        if check == 1:
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
        return render_template('dosomething.html', check = check) 
    return render_template('dosomething.html')
```

Comment: POST requests shouldn't render a response directly; they should issue a redirect to the appropriate page.  You're doing this if check is 1, but not otherwise.  Perhaps this is causing the issue.

Comment: Added an else statement to go to the dosomething html with check,  still does the same thing. It still has a post request on page load.

Comment: How have checked that post request occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must redirect with 307 http code.

```
if check == 1:
    return redirect(url_for('login'), code=307)
```